# window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send only works in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm creating a simple chrome extension and I want to detect whenever request is sent on a certain page, and I do it with this.

```
  window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = () => {
    alert('haha');
  }
```

Issue is that it works when I run this directly in console, so on every request I get alert('haha'), but when I run it from file, it doesn't work.

I tried with setTimeout, window.onload, simply calling function and every time I get message that function was invoked, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this from a content script? The details of how a chrome extension is put together are important. Including the manifest in your question is one way to provide this context.

Comment: Yes it's from content script..

  "content_scripts": [{
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": ["*://*.mydomain.com/*"],
    "js": ["./dist/custom.js"]
  }]

Comment: Chrome already provides a way of intercepting request calls using the [WebRequest api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script

Comment: Thanks Josh, thanks Patrick. These helped me a lot.